# How to block a user in QuickBlox?

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, quickblox, privacy

I am creating a chat based Application on `QuickBlox` Framework, I want to have a block functionality in the App. I read out some of documents like XMPP and `QuickBlox`. But did not got any help Out of that.

There is some logic of maintaining `QBPrivacyList` for not to allow other user send message and block it but I didn't got succeed with it.

This is a code snippet how I am maintaining the Privacy List.

1. Get the privacy list with Name `@"public"` in method of chat did login

   ```
   [[QBChat instance] retrievePrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
   ```

   so if there is already created privacy list named `"public"` will fetch it in delegate method

   ```
     - (void)chatDidReceivePrivacyList:(QBPrivacyList *)privacyList{
            NSLog(@"chatDidReceivePrivacyList: %@", privacyList);
            _blockPrivacyList = privacyList; // Save its instance for further add more users in list
       }
   ```

   // response is

   `[PrivacyList name: public]items:("type: USER_ID valueForType: 2075213 action: deny"`)
2. This is how add another member in privacy list

   ```
   - (void)blockUserWithQBId:(NSUInteger)qbID
   {

           QBPrivacyItem *item = [[QBPrivacyItem alloc] initWithType:USER_ID valueForType:qbID action:DENY];

           if (_blockPrivacyList) {
                 [_blockPrivacyList addObject:item]; // add new user if already privacy list is there
            }else
           _blockPrivacyList = [[QBPrivacyList alloc] initWithName:@"public" items:@[item]]; // create new privacy list if not before created

          [[QBChat instance] setPrivacyList:_blockPrivacyList];

   }
   ```

   And all the delegate methods works perfectly creates and adds member in privacy list.

   ```
   - (void)chatDidSetPrivacyListWithName:(NSString *)name{
     NSLog(@"chatDidSetPrivacyListWithName %@", name);
     [[QBChat instance] setDefaultPrivacyListWithName:name]; // set it as default privacy list
   }
   ```
3. I get this privacy list perfectly even i kill the app or Reinstall it for same user.
   so my privacy list code is working perfectly

But some how the other members in my `DENY` privacy list can send me message.
According to the documents from this http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list it should give the error like

```
 "error:Error Domain=com.quickblox.chat Code=503 "Service not available."
```

So if all privacy list works perfectly then how can my blocked users could send me messages?

I had worked with `XMPP` in `iOS` the same issue exist there also if you can give `XMPP` logic that will also work as `QuickBlox` as `QuickBlox` actually uses `XMPP` itself.

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found its solution. 
The flow and logic i had written in my question was perfect. I was just remaining with the one small function to activate the privacy list.
Dont know why `QuickBlox` has not written that function call in their demos.

```
    [[QBChat instance] setActivePrivacyListWithName:@"public"];
```

Same in XMPP we need to maintain the Privacy list and activate single privacy at one time.

Comment: Thank you Haresh, I was looking for exactly this, you saved my day! :)

Comment: Hi haresh, I added multiple users in the list and updated. How to remove the single user from the list and update.

Comment: Where did you add this code ? I tried to add it after connecting to chat. But still not working. Other user is still receiving messages. Can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct

Did you set the list with name "public" as the default one?
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Activate_a_privacy_list

Without it it won't be working

Comment: Yes i had set the privacy list name "public" as default. It works sometimes and some times not. Like other user still can send me message even i block it.